# Apply 'random' to an array

Tags: array, random

How do I output one random line of an array?

```
{% set img = [
  { bildli: 'http://i.giphy.com/I0xDz0htjsiME.gif' },
  { bildli: 'https://i.giphy.com/fA3JALhIi5YVa.gif' }
 ] %}
 {% for item in img %}
   <img src="{{ item.bildli }}" alt="">
 {% endfor %}
```

I tried `{% for item in img.limit(1).order('RAND()') %}` like you would on a normal `entries.section` but that doesn't work on array.

I also tried: `{% for item in random(img) %}` as statet in the twig doc but that doesn't work eyther. What's the catch here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `shuffle` function provided by Craft: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#shuffle

This will shuffle the complete array and output them all in the new order:

```
{% set img = [
    { bildli: 'http://i.giphy.com/I0xDz0htjsiME.gif' },
    { bildli: 'https://i.giphy.com/fA3JALhIi5YVa.gif' }
] %}

{% set shuffledImages = shuffle(img) %}

{% for item in shuffledImages %}
    <img src="{{ item.bildli }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to just output one random image, then this should work:

```
{% set img = [
    { bildli: 'http://i.giphy.com/I0xDz0htjsiME.gif' },
    { bildli: 'https://i.giphy.com/fA3JALhIi5YVa.gif' }
] %}

{% set randomImage = shuffle(img) | first %}

<img src="{{ randomImage.bildli }}" alt="">
```